# HTML 5 multi file upload with PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is the code I have, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong that it doesn't display the name.

```
<form action = "self.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imageURL[]" id="imageURL" multiple="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And the processing info that isn't working:

```
foreach ($_FILES['imageURL'] as $files[]) { 
    echo $files['file'];
}
```

**Edit:**

When changing my foreach loop to:

```
foreach ($_FILES['imageURL'] as $file) { 
    echo $file['name'];
}
```

Still nothing prints out.

However, when I do something like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES['imageURL']['name'] as $filename) { 
    echo $filename;
}
```

The filename does print. I don't know what that implies though.

**SOLVED UPDATE:**

As linked to by John Conde, the array interlace structure is different when uploading multiple files than when uploading a single file. To use foreach, we must restructure the array.

```
$files=array();
$fdata=$_FILES['imageURL'];
if(is_array($fdata['name'])){
for($i=0;$i<count($fdata['name']);++$i){
        $files[]=array(
    'name'    =>$fdata['name'][$i],
    'type'  => $fdata['type'][$i],
    'tmp_name'=>$fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
    'error' => $fdata['error'][$i], 
    'size'  => $fdata['size'][$i]  
    );
    }
}else $files[]=$fdata;
```

NOW we can use foreach to loop:

```
foreach ($files as $file) { 
    echo $file['name'];
}
```

Comment: The code under 'solved update' is rather poor.  is_array($fdata['name']) will always evaluate false, meaning most of the example never runs.  See the accepted answer on this page instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($_FILES['imageURL'] as $file) { 
    echo $file['name'];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Google found [this tutorial](http://verens.com/2009/12/28/multiple-file-uploads-using-html5/) which may help you

Comment: 's UPDATE: brilliant! that was the issue. The array structure is fundementally different which prevents foreach from looping over the files properly. What a horrible way to do that, I'm surprised there isn't a pre-built function in PHP to take care of this somehow...

Comment: @kylex: HTML5 is still in the design stages; PHP probably hasn't added direct support for it due to this.

Comment: Thank you so much for simple solution and for the resource link.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using for() and recounting the number of items in the array, you can use a more elegant foreach()

```
$files=array();
$fdata=$_FILES['file'];
if(is_array($fdata['name'])){
    foreach ($fdata['name'] as $i => $d) {
        $files[] = array(
        'name' => $d,
        'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i]
        );
    }
}
else $files[]=$fdata;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't setting `multiple=""` turn multiple uploads off?  Just use `multiple` by itself, as shown in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple) or, for XHTML compatibility, `multiple="multiple"`:

```
<input type="file" name="imageURL[]" id="imageURL" multiple />
```

Comment: A good thought, but not the issue. In fact the Firefox hacks section shows multiple as multiple=""