# JQuery html5 upload plugin. How do I use it?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I think I found a really cool JQuery file upload plugin but it seems they do not have a PHP server side example and I'm a little overwhelmed on how to set it up.

Can you kindly help me out and show me how to use it?

Here's the link to their page:

https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload

Comment: Have you contacted the script author? Seems like this is something he should be providing as part of the documentation. (Incidentally, you might also take a look at http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ which is more complete in that respect.)

Comment: No. There's an option for the upload URL. The PHP script is not part of the plugin.

Comment: You might also take a look at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-345) - example #3 gives an instance of processing multiple files (but with a different approach to the HTML).

Comment: A google search for "php HTML5 multiple file upload" returned [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3215324/901048).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the plugin, but basically you need to set an URL where the files should be "sent" to (take a look at the example.html file on github):

```
$("#upload_field").html5_upload({
    url: /*PATH TO PHP FILE.php*/,
    ...
```

The PHP file depends on what you want to do: Store the files in a database, store them on the server... However, if you want to store them in a folder, take a look at this code I used in a HTML5 file uploader:

```
//Count files
$count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    //Path
    $filepath = 'upload/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);

    //Save file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $filepath);
}
```

It's very basic, it doesn't check for errors, file types and things like that. Remember to adjust the input name: `$_FILES['INPUT NAME HERE'][.....`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at [jquery-html5-upload](https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload), but it is still very *young*, low documentation and demos, no server side demo, etc...!

On the other hand, here's a good tutorial to get you on the right track with HTML5 and Jquery for File Uploads:

[Tutorial :: html5-file-upload-jquery-php](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)

[html5uploader](http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/)

and my personal favorite: [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

**Ps:**

Place a [request](https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload/issues?sort=created&state=closed) on the jquery-html5-upload for the author include a server side example.