# Only last image uploaded from array when uploading multiple images in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: arrays, file, upload, insert, foreach

I'm trying to upload multiple images from a textbox to MYSQL database using PHP.
But somehow it only inserts the last item from the array in the database.

I tried uploading using one image, and that worked.

What am I doing wrong?

**form.php:**

```
<form action="addpicture.php?id=<?php echo $prodID; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="image" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
</form>
```

**Addpicture.php:**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include '../includes/config.php';

    $prodID = $_GET['id'];

    foreach(array_keys($_FILES['image']['error']) as $key){
    $temp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $t_name = file_get_contents($temp_name);
    $t_name = mysql_real_escape_string($t_name);

    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblpictures(prodID, foto) VALUES ('$prodID','$t_name')") or die(mysql_error());          

            header('location: form.php?prodID=' . $prodID);
            exit();
    }

    ?>
```

***EDIT: SOLVED***
[HTML 5 multi file upload with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215324/html-5-multi-file-upload-with-php)

Comment: `addslashes()` is to SQL injection prevention as using a roll of toilet paper is to soaking up an ocean. Do **NOT** use it. You may think you're doing the right thing, but it's NOT a defense against sql injection in any real way.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get an sql error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
I don't know what could be wrong to my sql

Answer (score 0):

You're using the PHP array-based naming for file uploads. PHP's treatment of that in the $_FILES array is BEYOND moronic.

Single files show up as

```
$_FILES = array(
   'fieldname' => array('error' => ..., 'name' => '...', etc....)
);
```

As soon as you go into array mode, you get a completely DIFFERENT structure:

```
$_FILES = array(
   'fieldname' => array (
       'error' => array(
            0 => 'error code of first file'
            1 => 'error code of second file'
            etc...
       )
       'name' => array(
            0 => 'first filename',
            1 => 'second filename',
            etc...
       )
   )
)
```

You need to loop on:

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['image']['error']) as $key) {
    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
}
```

Comment: don't post code into a comment. editor your question and put it there.