# Multiple Image Upload PHP form with one input

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading, multiple-file-upload

I've been trying to make this work for quite some time now. But I can't seem to make it work. I wanted to have a multiple image upload form with only using one input.

this is my upload.php

```
<?php
include("../include/session.php");

session_start();
$allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]));

if(isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))
{
    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);$i++)
    {

        if (($_FILES["upload"]["name"] < 90000000000000000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
                if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                    header('location: '.$error); die;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (file_exists("../icons/".$_SESSION["username"] ."/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]))
                    {
                    echo "error";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(!is_dir("../icons/". $_SESSION["username"] ."/")) {
                            mkdir("../icons/". $_SESSION["username"] ."/");
                        }

                        $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
                        $file = rand(1,999999999999) . '.' .end($temp);

                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "../icons/". $_SESSION["username"] ."/". $file);  
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "yep error";
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

if i take out the lines

```
if(isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))
{
    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);$i++)
    {
```

With the corresponding closing bracket, it seems to work fine. The image is uploaded perfectly. But the thing is, it only allows me to upload one.

Please I really need your expertise. THank you

Comment: notice this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215324/html-5-multi-file-upload-with-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118633/upload-more-than-one-image-to-a-server-folder Here you can go through the link for answer

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$error=array();
$extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(in_array($ext,$extension)) {
        if(!file_exists("photo_gallery/".$txtGalleryName."/".$file_name)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"photo_gallery/".$txtGalleryName."/".$file_name);
        }
        else {
            $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
            $newFileName=$filename.time().".".$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"photo_gallery/".$txtGalleryName."/".$newFileName);
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($error,"$file_name, ");
    }
}
```

and you must check your HTML code

```
<form action="create_photo_gallery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Select Photo (one or multiple):</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Note: Supported image format: .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Create Gallery" id="selectedButton"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Nice link on:

[**PHP Single File Uploading with vary basic explanation**](http://www.javascripthive.info/php/php-file-uploading/).

[**PHP file uploading with the Validation**](http://www.javascripthive.info/php/php-file-uploading-validation/)

[**PHP Multiple Files Upload With Validation Click here to download source code**](http://www.javascripthive.info/php/php-multiple-files-upload-validation/)

[**PHP/jQuery Multiple Files Upload With The ProgressBar And Validation (Click here to download source code)**](http://www.javascripthive.info/php/php-and-jquery-multiple-files-upload-progressbar-validation/)

[**How To Upload Files In PHP And Store In MySql Database (Click here to download source code)**](http://www.javascripthive.info/php/upload-files-using-php-and-store-in-mysql-database/)

Comment: and how to save these images to database?

Comment: @AsifMehmood It's really not a nice idea to save an image as a blob file to the database, except you're working on a small and none SEO seeking project.

Comment: @AsifMehmood please take a look here: http://www.javascripthive.info/php/upload-files-using-php-and-store-in-mysql-database/

Comment: Why use `extract($_POST);` ? I remove it and the codes work well. And `extract` on `$_POST` seems is poor coding practices. You could find the warning  __"Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.)"__ in the php.net manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: @PreciousTom SO whats the alternative for not saving the images to database?

Comment: You get to store an image in a file directory and save the path in your database, this is pretty much the alternative i can think of. @AsifMehmood

Comment: @PreciousTom what if i accedentally deleted that pic from my phone so my data is going to be lost, i thin that is't the proper way.

Comment: As a programmer you learn to backup datas, or work with bigger companies , cloudhost, more of such. Besides, if you want a good SEO for your site you'll stick to saving an image to a directory else if it's a small scale site leave your image in a db. @AsifMehmood

Comment: All the additional links were broken, so I have removed them

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Image upload using php full source code and preview available at the below Link.
Sample code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { //loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).
        ".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1; //increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { //if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else { //if file was not moved.
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else { //if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j.
            ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.allinworld99.blogspot.com/2015/05/php-multiple-file-upload.html

Comment: Id just like to add to this, the initial $target_path variable needs to be inside the for loop, otherwise the file names that are hashed via md5 are concatenated. 

Additionally, i removed the hashed file name method as it wasnt right for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnSave'])){
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $file_name_all="";

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images

    //loop to get individual element from the array
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable
        $basename=basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        //echo"hi its base name".$basename;
        $target_path = $target_path .$basename;//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < (1024*1024)) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
        && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
                /***********************************************/

                $file_name_all.=$target_path."*";  
                $filepath = rtrim($file_name_all, '*');  
                //echo"<img src=".$filepath."   >";          

                /*************************************************/
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
    $qry="INSERT INTO `eb_re_about_us`(`er_abt_us_id`, `er_cli_id`, `er_cli_abt_info`, `er_cli_abt_img`) VALUES (NULL,'$b1','$b5','$filepath')";


    $res = mysql_query($qry,$conn); 
    if($res)
        echo "<br/><br/>Client contact Person Information Details Saved successfully";
        //header("location: nextaddclient.php");
        //exit();
    else
        echo "<br/><br/>Client contact Person Information Details not saved successfully";

}
?>
```

Here  **$file_name_all** And **$filepath** get 1 uplode file name 2 time?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? If so, please state clearly in how far it solves the question. If this is a question in itself, delete it here and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include('config.php');
//define session id
$session_id='1'; 
define ("MAX_SIZE","9000"); 
function getExtension($str)
{
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
}

//set the image extentions
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{

    $uploaddir = "uploads/"; //image upload directory
    foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
        $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
        //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
          $ext = getExtension($filename);
          $ext = strtolower($ext);

         if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
         {
           if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
           {
           $image_name=time().$filename;
           echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>";
           $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;

           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname)) 
           {
           $time=time();
               //insert in database
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_uploads(image_name,user_id_fk,created) VALUES('$image_name','$session_id','$time')");
           }
           else
           {
            echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit! so moving unsuccessful! </span>';
            }

           }
           else
           {
            echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';

           }

          }
          else
         { 
             echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';

         }

     }
}

?>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function()            { 

                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
                     beforeSubmit:function(){ 

                    console.log('ttest');
                    $("#imageloadstatus").show();
                     $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
                     }, 
                    success:function(){ 
                    console.log('test');
                     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                     $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                    }, 
                    error:function(){ 
                    console.log('xtest');
                     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                    $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                    } }).submit();


            });
        }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple image upload with other table
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO event(title) VALUES('$title')";

```
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        $lastid= $connection->insert_id;
        foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
                $name = $lastid.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
                $target_dir = "photo/";
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO photos(image,eventid) VALUES ('".$target_dir.$name."','".$lastid."')";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],$target_dir.$name);
            }
        }
```

And how to fetch

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
       

  if($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $eventid= $r['id'];
        $sqli="select id,image from photos where eventid='".$eventid."'";
        $resulti=mysqli_query($connection,$sqli);
        $image_json_array = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti)){
            $image_id = $row['id'];
            $image_name = $row['image'];
            $image_json_array[] = array("id"=>$image_id,"name"=>$image_name);
        }
        $msg1[] = array ("imagelist" => $image_json_array);
        
      }
```

in ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addCAT').validate({
        rules: {
            name: required: true
        }
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var formurl = $(form).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: formurl,
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(form),
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    window.location.href = "{{ url('admin/listcategory')}}";
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = count($_FILES['txt_gallery']['name']);
            $filename_arr = [];
            $filename_arr1 = [];
            for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
              $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['txt_gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];
              if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                $newFilePath = "../uploaded/" .date('Ymdhis').$i.$_FILES['txt_gallery']['name'][$i];
                $newFilePath1 = date('Ymdhis').$i.$_FILES['txt_gallery']['name'][$i];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                  $filename_arr[] = $newFilePath;
                  $filename_arr1[] = $newFilePath1;

                }
              }
            }
            $file_names = implode(',', $filename_arr1);
            var_dump($file_names); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $val) {
$allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
$fileName = basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);
$tempName = basename($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
$fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$fileNameFinal = $empID . '_' . date('Y-m-d_His') . '.' . $fileExt;

if (in_array($fileExt, $allowTypes)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/' . $fileNameFinal)) {

        $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO apimultiimage (EmployeeID, token, image) VALUES('" . $empID . "','" . $token . "','" . $fileNameFinal . "')");

        $result['msg'] = 'Inserted.';
        $result['status'] = 1;
    } else {
        $result['msg'] = 'Not Inserted.';
        $result['status'] = 0;
    }
} else {
    $result['msg'] = 'Please select a file type jpg / jpeg / png / gif to upload.';
    $result['status'] = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).