# Upload more than one image to a server folder

Tags: php

I have a form through which a user can upload images to a server folder, and the path gets saved in the database.

Currently the code that I have works fine when the user has to input only one image; however, I want to do something like the following with the form, so that user can upload more than one image:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="insertimage.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Select Image 1</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input  type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Select Image 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input  type="file" name="file1" id="fileToUpload">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Select Image 3</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input  type="file" name="file2" id="fileToUpload">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit" name="submit">
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

The PHP code at back end for uploading one image is `insertimage.php`:

```
<?php
$file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
                // Enter your path to upload file here
                if (file_exists("uploads/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                    {
                        echo "<div class='error'>"."(".$_FILES["file"]["name"].")"." already exists. "."</div>";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        echo "<div class='sucess'>"."Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."</div>";
    `               }
            }
    }
else
    {
        echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
    }
?>
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can support uploading 3 images with help of the above code?

Answer (score 2):

With this you are able to select multiple image with use of ctrl

```
 <input  type="file" name="file[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple />
```

On Server side use loop

```
 for ($1=0;i<count($dataFile);$i++){
    //your upload code ; 
    $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];//go for each and every i position for all 
 }
```

Comment: i wish that user can upload only 5 images so will that also work with this code?

Comment: yes this code is run for total no of selected images and if fix to 5 images you have to change count to 5 at php code side

Answer (score 0):

You can use file array for multiple images at a time with multiple attribute in the html line like:

```
<input  type="file" name="file[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple />
```

This will give you the array of files which you can debug by

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

And you also have to change the code that saves the data as there is error that it can only have one file at a time try for loop my debugging with

```
$_FILES
```

Comment: i wish to upload the images separately so kind of avoiding to use multiple keyword

Comment: if u want to avoid multiple keyword then you have to add file tag as many time you want to uploaad image and in that you have to pass same file name so it create an array and it will solve your problem

Comment: For maximum 5 files you will have too validate the input at view level to take only 5 files.