# While creating a directory and upload multiple files with single browse button

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload multiple files with single browse button, but I couldn't got success through it . I tried suggestion mentioned in similar query. Below code is only uploading one file, I need to upload more than file with same browse button.

Any idea what is wrong in the code?

```
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadj.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple /><br />



  <p>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
  </p>

</form>


</html>
</body>

Php Code :


   <?php

$get_folder = $_POST['textfield'];
mkdir ("/opt/lampp/htdocs/test_upload/" . $get_folder, 0777);
echo "Analysis Directory created successfully";

$target_path = "$get_folder/";


for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);$i++){



$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
{
    echo "The file has been uploaded";

} else

{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


}



?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: $_FILES['uploadedfile'][0]['name']

You should do: $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0]

I have updated this code to support multiple uploads. Let me know if this works

```
     for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);$i++){
      $target_path = ""; //to clear the values on each loop//
      $target_path = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  As I tried your suggestion but by it only one file is uploading ,not more than one. Do you what can be the reason ?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can do something like this:
 
       `code`   
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);$i++){
      $target_path = ""; //to clear the values on each loop//
      $target_path = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path);
     }

 `code`


Let me know if this works!

Cheers

Comment: No this  part I have already tried but only one file is uploading , i need more than one file to be uploaded.

Comment: Can you update your code with what you have done so far?

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path);

If you put this on that loop it should upload multiple files because $i is changing on each iteration.

Comment: Here is the revised php code :<?php

$get_folder = $_POST['textfield'];
mkdir ("/opt/lampp/htdocs/test_upload/" . $get_folder, 0777);
echo "Analysis Directory created successfully";

$target_path = "$get_folder/";


for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);$i++){



$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
{
    echo "The file has been uploaded";

} else

{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


}



?>

Comment: This looks too weird. Idk what you are planning to do here but with that con-cat thing the file name will be so long. Can you try this instead:

$upload_folder   = "$get_folder/";
$target_path       = $upload_folder. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a directory then to upload files in it. So with one file its working perfectly, but not with more than file.I tried your suggestion mentione above , but still its the same.

Comment: Okay, so you are uploading all the files on the folder that was just created right? And also did you try to check print_r($_FILES); and see if all the images you are uploading are coming through?

Comment: Yes I checked but only the one file is uploading.

Comment: Do you know what can be the problem in it ??

Comment: You know with basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]); it will remove all the extensions from the file?  If the extensions r gone, it wont be saved as an image. It will be just be an Object. And i am not sure why is it not working because, i just did a demo code with your forms and I got  :
Array ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [1] => Desert.jpg [2] => Hydrangeas.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] =>) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] =>) [error] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2  ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0) ) )

Comment: But the code is for text files. I am also trying to upload text files. But I getting this Analysis Directory created successfullyThe file has been uploadedArray ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Dokument.txt ) [type] => Array ( [0] => text/plain ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpUWqhj4 ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) ) )

Comment: I used your form and then removed the action from the form, and did print_r($_FILES) and 
for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);$i++) {
 echo $target_path = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i])."<BR>";
}

Array ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Example.odt [1] =>acb.pdf ) [type] => Array ( [0] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text [1] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpTqTLD0 [1] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 36227 [1] => 0 ) ) ) 
Example.odt
acb.pdf

I am not sure mate! This should definitely works,

Comment: But without action how it recognize the php script. Can you please edited in your previous php code, b/c its showing an error.

Answer (score 0):

One error you have is you are using `$target_path` before defining it.  The line I am referring to is:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile'][0]['name']);
```

You cannot use `$target_path` on the right side when it has not been previously defined.  On top of that the 0 is in the wrong position.  It should be `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0]`.

Other errors you may have:

1. Not a high enough file upload size in php.ini
2. Not a high enough max input size in php.ini
3. Folder is not writable by the webserver user (often www-data or apache)

**UPDATE**

Another error, is that you are simply appending to `$target_path` in your loop this makes it so that the second iteration is trying to use the previous upload as a folder, which is not allowed.  For an example, if I uploaded foo.png and bar.jpg the second target path would be `/opt/lampp/htdocs/test_upload/foo.png/bar.png`, which is not a valid path.

I would solve this in your loop by changing this line:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);
```

to:

```
 $target_file =  $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);
```

And change:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
```

to:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file))
```

**UPDATE 2**

The following code works on my server (Ubuntu Server with upload folder belonging to www-data and permission of 755):

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'):?>
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index2.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple /><br />



  <p>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
  </p>

</form>


</html>
</body>

<?php else: ?>

<?php

$target_path = "./videos/";


for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);$i++){



$target_file = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file))
{
    echo "The file has been uploaded";

} else

{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


}
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I corrected the target.path by defining it previously. But the problem is that its only uploading one file, not more than one file.

Comment: @Kabhir that is because you have use a loop to get to each item.

Comment: @ Travis You check my revised code I am using loop in it.But with that its only uploading one file-

Comment: @Kabhir you are using ```$target_path``` by appending to it in your loop.  Since you used it in your previous iteration the second path would be something like '/opt/lampp/htdocs/test_upload/foo.png/bar.jpg' and since foo.png is a file not a folder it cannot move it to that location.  I will update my answer.

Comment: I am trying to upload text files .Actually I am trying to create a directory then to upload files in it. So with one file its working perfectly, but not with more than file.

Comment: @Kabhir It is the same as if you were uploading image files, you have an invalid path on the second one because of how you are using ```$target_file```.  See my updated answer, hopefully it will help.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work even after update in answer. Its still uploading only one file.

Comment: @Kabhir that is weird because I have tried it and it allows me to upload multiple files.  You can see the example code I used in my answer.

Comment: But what about you have not mentioned code for  creating directory in it, b/c that is my requirement of code . As I mentioned above.

Comment: @Kabhir, it seems like you are not having a problem creating a folder from what I understand, so I have removed that piece of code.  You can add that piece of code back in to create your folder.

Answer (score 0):

FORM:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple /><br />

 <p>
 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
 </p>

</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
 if(isset($_POST['button'])){
     $upload_folder = "./textfiles/";
     for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);$i++){
          $target_path = ""; //to clear the values on each loop//
          $target_path = $upload_folder.basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]);
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
             {
             //do your redirect
             }else {
                //do your redirect
             }
   }
  }
```

NOTE: The php code will go on top of the form!. I have tested this code and it works good on my end:

Comment: I admire your help. Thanks a lot for your patience. But when I click on browse button (For example when I click browse button first time then the du.txt is loaded and when I click browse button second time then Document.txt is loaded.  But when I am clicking on submit button then only one last file is submitted which is Document.txt and I need both files ). This is the problem .Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah, this might be problem. Try doing this:

When you click on the browse button; press ctrl and then click on multiple files that you need to upload.