# Upload multiple images using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the code below and I can't seem to figure out why my query is failing. Do anyone have an idea why?

I have tried many suggested solutions that I found online but none of them worked.

The HTML form code follows the PHP code

```
<?php include 'connection.php';?>

<?php
    $dir           = substr(uniqid(),-7);
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb

    /*
       $path = "Prototype/uploads/"; // Upload directory
       mkdir ($path, 0744);\
    */

    $count = 0;

    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {   
            echo "$name--";
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip file if any error found
                echo "something <br>";
            }          

            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    echo "something***************** <br>";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                } elseif (! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)) {
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    echo "something+++++++++++++++++++ <br>";
                    echo "$name-- ";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                } else { // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                    // if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                    // $count=$count+1; // Number of successfully uploaded file             
                    //echo $path.$name;

                    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f]));
                    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['files']['name'][$f]);
                    $query2 = "Insert into $dbname.Image (Image, ImageName) VALUES ('$image', '$image_name')";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);

                    if (!$result2) {
                        echo "ERRORS";
                    }

                    //Number of successfully uploaded file

                }
            }
        }
        echo "$count files were imported";
    }

    //show success message
    /*
        echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    

        if(is_array($files)){
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($files as $file){
                echo "<li>$file</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    */
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
    <input id="my-file-selector" type="file"  name="files[]" style="display:none;" multiple onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());">
    Browse
  </label>
  <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
  <div style="float:right;">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector2">
      <input id="my-file-selector2" type="Submit" style="display:none;" name="search">
      Save
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what error are you facing ?

Comment: This condition `if (!$result2)` is failing so I assume something is wrong.

Comment: print your $_FILES array and check what its returns

Comment: Sorry if it's sound stupid. Are you asking me to print the variable `$name` (`foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name)`)?

Comment: compare your code with this link it will help you. http://www.mostlikers.com/2014/03/multiple-image-upload-concept-using-php.html

Comment: If `echo "ERRORS"` is executed, then your `mysqli_query($conn,$query2)` failed. Print `$query2` and see if it is as you expect. (Possibly `$dbname.Image` causes trouble.)

Comment: @vighaneshmandavkar Thanks for the link but they are saving the path of the images but on my side I store the actual image (`longblob` type).\

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for the suggestion, my query is as expected!

Comment: what does it say when you echo mysqli_error($conn);

Comment: I'm pretty much sure the error isn't coming from the connection.

Comment: You use `addslashes()` and you never check for query errors. In short, you are not using `mysqli` correctly. There should be lots of examples in the PHP manual.

Comment: @Bobby where you have to store you actual image to a folder or to a database.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  I had a small script to import a single image and I used the exact query (and addslashes()) so not sure how I'm not using it correctly in this case

Comment: @vighaneshmandavkar I want to store it in the actual database

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not to save images directly to database.

Rather you can either move the files to cloud services like S3 and store that url in database.

if S3 is not your choice, Please upload the image to any folder in the same project and store that url.

Is there any specific reason to store the binary image in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

link:-[Multiple Image Upload PHP form with one input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input)