# ajax with multiple content type form with jscript

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

Before Ajax i used simple form with some text input and files, but in ajax php throws error that files are not defined.
https://jsfiddle.net/wkLvh8rj/
here is addtodata.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) &&
isset($_GET['ad']) &&
isset($_FILES['pic1']) &&
isset($_FILES['pic2']) &&
isset($_FILES['pic3']) &&
!isset($_GET["web"]) &&
!isset($_GET["mob"]) &&
!isset($_FILES["pic"]))
{echo "working";}
else{echo "not working";}
```

So what i'm doing wrong? or what i'm missing?

Comment: Why are you not using multiple image uploading functionality? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input

Comment: Possible duplicate [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: but in my case what should i do?