# How can I upload img[] and rename it when it save?

Tags: php

I use w3school example

1) How can I rename when I add img because I want to add same image with same name I want to rename?

2) If my `fileToupload[]` how can I upload use `for(i=0 ,i< ? ,i++)`

Should I use `count($_FILES)`?

Here  my code:

```
$target_dir = "../../_files/images/source/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = md5($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
         var_dump($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can read this stack answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input

Comment: @iCoders thank you sir

Comment: hope that link will help you to solve your problem

Comment: thanks it work now =] @iCoders

Answer (score 0):

Just update the value of $target_file every time, it will rename image name automatically.

Comment: can  you give me an example ? please