# Get Data Detail By ID - CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

when i get the data by id, just only display first row from table

This is my controller

```
public function getDetail($id=true)
{

    $data['detail'] = $this->vendor_model->getDetail($id);
    $this->load->view('vendor/detailvendor',$data);

}
```

this is my model

```
 public function getDetail($id)
{

    $this->db->where('no_spk',$id);
    $query = $this->db->query("select a.no_spk, a.nama_pekerjaan, a.alamat, a.latitude, a.longitude, b.nama_vendor, c.progress, c.keterangan, c.gambar, c.gambar2, c.gambar3, d.namapekerja from vendor as b inner join pekerjaan as a on b.id_vendor = a.id_vendor inner join progress as c on c.no_spk = a.no_spk inner join pekerja as d on d.id_pekerja=c.id_pekerja");
    return $query->result();
}
```

And, this is my view

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('homevendor/getDetail'.$this->uri->segment(4)); ?>
<?php echo $detail[0]->no_spk?><br>
<?php echo $detail[0]->nama_pekerjaan?><br>
<?php echo $detail[0]->progress?><br>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

the result is[view on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgPQN.jpg)
[content of table, there are 2 data but only show first data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6e96.jpg)

please help me

Comment: You want to fetch a single row. Right ?

Comment: Edit your question add codeigniter tag so you get better help.

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: Check the answer if you still need help i am available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.For getting and showing all records, only change `view` file code like below:-***

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('homevendor/getDetail'.$this->uri->segment(4)); ?>
  <?php foreach($detail as $deta){?>
    <?php echo $deta->no_spk?><br>
    <?php echo $deta->nama_pekerjaan?><br>
    <?php echo $deta->progress?><br>
  <?php }?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

***2.For getting and showing single records, use `LIMI 1` in query and change view code also like below:-***

Modal code:-

```
public function getDetail($id){
   $this->db->where('no_spk',$id);
   $query = $this->db->query("select a.no_spk, a.nama_pekerjaan, a.alamat, a.latitude, a.longitude, b.nama_vendor, c.progress, c.keterangan, c.gambar, c.gambar2, c.gambar3, d.namapekerja from vendor as b inner join pekerjaan as a on b.id_vendor = a.id_vendor inner join progress as c on c.no_spk = a.no_spk inner join pekerja as d on d.id_pekerja=c.id_pekerja LIMIT 1");
   return $query->result();
}
```

And view:-

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('homevendor/getDetail'.$this->uri->segment(4)); ?>
  <?php foreach($detail as $deta){?>
    <?php echo $deta->no_spk?><br>
    <?php echo $deta->nama_pekerjaan?><br>
    <?php echo $deta->progress?><br>
  <?php }?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: give me a minute to try that

Comment: by the way thankyou because u help me, i got error because my mistake on button "DETAIL"  typo :))) but thankyou your very is very help me to code next time

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getDetail($id)
{

    //$this->db->where('no_spk',$id);
    $query = $this->db->query("select a.no_spk, a.nama_pekerjaan, a.alamat, a.latitude, a.longitude, b.nama_vendor, c.progress, c.keterangan, c.gambar, c.gambar2, c.gambar3, d.namapekerja from vendor as b inner join pekerjaan as a on b.id_vendor = a.id_vendor inner join progress as c on c.no_spk = a.no_spk inner join pekerja as d on d.id_pekerja=c.id_pekerja WHERE c.no_spk=".$id);
    return $query->row();
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('homevendor/getDetail'.$this->uri->segment(4)); ?>
<?php echo $detail->no_spk?><br>
<?php echo $detail->nama_pekerjaan?><br>
<?php echo $detail->progress?><br>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**Explanation**

You are looking for to fetch a single row.Use row function instead of result.
Codeigniter database class row function returns an object. SO you will be able to use the -> to accessing the object data.

Comment: i will try that, give me a minute

Comment: I updated my answer just copy the model function and paste it again.

Comment: by the way thankyou because u help me, i got error because my mistake on button "DETAIL"  typo :))) but thankyou your very is very help me to code next time

Comment: by the way help me to upload multiple images, i was post my question but i'm still confused @Adnanhaider

Comment: I don't know your exact question. But check this link before posting any question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input