# How to change single image upload php to multi image upload

Tags: php

I am new to php. I want to know how to change single image upload php to multi image upload.

Below is my code:-

```
<?php
require_once("header.php");
require_once("nav.php");   

// Count total files
  $countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "frm_add_channel")) {
if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{
  $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
  $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"images/album" . $_FILES['image']['name']);

  $albumid = $_POST['albumid'];
  $name = str_replace("'","''",$name);
  $place = $_POST['place'];
  $place = str_replace("'","''",$place);
  $owner = $_POST['owner'];
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (name,image,sys_album_id)
  VALUES ('$path','$name','$albumid')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  //$int_id = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $int_id = mysql_num_rows();



  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Successfully Add New Channel!");location.href="gallery_upload.php";</script>';
    }
  }
?>




<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>
        <form name="frm_add_channel" method="post" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <h4>Image (Less Than 2MB)</h4>
          <img src="upload/qm.jpg" id="imgAvatar" alt="Course Image" />
          <p><input type="file" name="image" id="image" onChange="showPreview(this)" accept="image/*" multiple /></p><br>



<input type="text" class="form" name="albumid" value"<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" size="30" />
          <p><input type="submit" value="Add Album" onclick="return checking()" /></p><br>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="frm_add_channel">
        </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input

Comment: The PHP manual has a page on that topic: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 1):

try this below changed html & PHP file

```
   $countfiles = count($_FILES['image']['name']);


   for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++)
   {

      $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]));
      $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],"images/album" . $_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
       ......
       ....
   }



 <form name="frm_add_channel" method="post" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                  <h4>Image (Less Than 2MB)</h4>
                  <img src="upload/qm.jpg" id="imgAvatar" alt="Course Image" />
                  <p><input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" onChange="showPreview(this)" multiple /></p><br>



        <input type="text" class="form" name="albumid" value"<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" size="30" />
                  <p><input type="submit" value="Add Album" onclick="return checking()" /></p><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="frm_add_channel">
                </form>
```

Comment: I am still getting one image uploaded