# Uploading multiple images only uploads one

Tags: php

I have this script that is receiving data from a vue js client

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");


$image = '';

if(isset($_FILES['property_files']['name']))
{
 $image_name = $_FILES['property_files']['name'];
 $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");
 $extension = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 if(in_array($extension, $valid_extensions))
 {
  $upload_path = 'uploads/' . time() . '.' . $extension;
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['property_files']['tmp_name'], $upload_path))
  {
   $message = 'Image Uploaded';
   $image = $upload_path;
  }
  else
  {
   $message = 'There is an error while uploading image';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $message = 'Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png Image allowed to upload';
 }
}
else
{
 $message = 'Select Image';
}

$output = array(
 'url'   => $image
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

I want the final output to be

```
[{
  "url": "/absolute/path/to/filename.png"
}]
```

So far when i upload one image it works but more than one image, the script only uploads one image and for subsequent images it only echos duplicate image paths. How can i make the script upload multiple images?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895170/multiple-image-upload-php-form-with-one-input

Answer (score 0):

I changed `time()` to `uniqid()` and worked perfectly

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");


$image = '';

if(isset($_FILES['property_files']['name']))
{
 $image_name = $_FILES['property_files']['name'];
 $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");
 $extension = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 if(in_array($extension, $valid_extensions))
 {
  $upload_path = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['property_files']['tmp_name'], $upload_path))
  {
   $message = 'Image Uploaded';
   $image = $upload_path;
  }
  else
  {
   $message = 'There is an error while uploading image';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $message = 'Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png Image allowed to upload';
 }
}
else
{
 $message = 'Select Image';
}

$output = array(
 'url'   => $image
);

echo json_encode($output);
```